# UITextField and Keyboard Notifications - strange order

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield, uitextview, uikeyboard

So I've set up a notification for the keyboard appearance event. Now let us consider a UITextView and a UITextField.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

The selector is:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {

        keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
}
```

In case of a UITextView, the delegate method `- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView` is fired **AFTER** the `keyboardWillShow:` method. So keyboardSize has the keyboard's actual size and I'm able to use that inside the textview delegate method.

However in case of a UITextField, the corresponding delegate method `- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` is fired **BEFORE** the `keyboardWillShow:` method.

Why is this so? How do I get the keyboard's `CGSize` in the textfield's case as now it just returns zero because the textfield delegate is called first and not the keyboard selector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Weird…  Sounds like a mistake on Apple's end.

Maybe you could delay the keyboard popping up?  Here's my unfortunately very messy "work around" suggestion --  You could send a notification when the text field is selected, but then only actually begin editing a fraction of a second later so that the text field is in fact known before `keyboardWillShow:` is called.  For example:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    // Notification corresponding to "textFieldSelected:" method
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_TEXT_FIELD_SELECTED object:nil userInfo:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:textField, @"textField", nil]];

    // "textFieldReallyShouldBeginEditing" is initially set as FALSE elsewhere in the code before the text field is manually selected
    if (textFieldReallyShouldBeginEditing)
        return YES;
    else
        return NO:
}

- (void)textFieldSelected:(NSNotification*)notification {

    // Done in a separate method so there's a guaranteed delay and "textFieldReallyShouldBeginEditing" isn't set to YES before "textFieldShouldBeginEditing:" returns its boolean. 
    [self performSelector:@selector(startTextFieldReallyEditing:) withObject:(UITextField*)notification[@"textField"] afterDelay:.01];
}

- (void)startTextFieldReallyEditing:(UITextField*)textField {
    textFieldReallyShouldBeginEditing = YES;

    // To trigger the keyboard
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Then depending on how you're creating the notification, you can insert the value of this now known text field even before it begins editing.

Comment: In my case simple dispatch_async(mainQueue, ^{}) helped.

Answer (score 5):

I've had this same problem. Try using:

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
```

Comment: The question is about textfield and you suggest textview delegate method. I don't get it, what's the point?

Comment: The answer might be irrelevant to this problem but it solved the issue in my case. Thanks!

Comment: textField has a simliar delegate method, I would imagine that it likewise will solve the problem: textFieldShouldBeginEditing